# Is there an R function which can take a partial derivative of a function which requires a loop?

Tags: r, derivative

I have a function in R which requires the use of a for loop because later values of the vector depend on previous values of the vector. I need to take partial derivatives of this function.

I have tried using the `Deriv::Deriv` function which allows you to supply a function instead of an expression like `deriv`.

I've included a simplification of my function:

```
fn=function(b1,omega){
  R=12
  S=10
  curmean=rep(b1,R)
  for (each in 2:S){
    curmean=c(curmean,omega*(curmean[((each-2)*R+1):((each-1)*R)]))
  }
  curmean
}
fn(.04,.8)
Deriv(fn,x=c('b1'))(.004,.8)
```

This code should return a vector when the function is provided inputs `b1=.04` and `omega=.8` (which it does) as well as a vector resulting from those values after the partial derivative of `b1` is taken.

`Error in Deriv_(a, x[ix], env, use.D, dsym, scache) : 
  Could not retrieve body of 'for()'`

Is there a workaround for this? Maybe symbolic language to create the vector?

Comment: Do you need it to be a symbolic version of the partial derivative or would a numerical partial derivative work for your use case?

Comment: @Dason numerical partial derivative will work in my case.